# Upload Image on form submit

Tags: 7, media, forms, files

I have a form with an image field, I want to remove the upload button and submit the image while the form is submitted. I not able to find out how to proceed further with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the HTML of the page, find the `id` of the input/upload button, then hide it via a `display:none;` in your css will get you going quickly; otherwise, you will have to do a form_alter() in drupal to remove it from the form.

Comment: that is fine, what about the part where _submit the image while the form is submitted_?

Comment: you still have the "choose" part of the form there, don't you?  that allows you to choose the file from the client, and then when you submit the form, it grabs it.  unless I am totally missing something here.

Comment: oops ..my bad .. for some reason, it wasn't uploading the image previously with the form submit! thanks a ton though!